# PHP - Scandir with special characters

Tags: php, special-characters, scandir

I'm trying to list the files in a certain folder, but some folders have special characters such as a degree symbol. Using scandir () or RecursiveDirectoryIterator errors occur. I did some tests isolating the folder and removing the special character and it works.
Is there any way to handle this? I researched and did not find something that works. I tried a few things like using iconv() but nothing worked.

[image]

Using scandir on folder named "Fornos 1200°C" gives this error "failed to open dir: No such file or directory"
Using scandir on folder named "Fornos 1200C" it works.

Comment: What platform are you on? On CentOS PHP 7.4 this works perfectly fine. Please share your code.

Comment: Windows Server 2008. 
I did another test and saved the script with encoding "Windows 1252" and it apparently worked.
Before the script was being saved as "UTF8"

Answer (score 0):

I did another test and saved the script with encoding "Windows 1252" and it apparently worked. Before the script was being saved as "UTF8"